# NHibernate with Castle, HQL could not locate parameter [param]

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, castle-activerecord

I have an HQL query on a class mapped with Castle ActiveRecord and get the following error: NHibernate.QueryParameterException: could not located named parameter [param].

Here's my class, simplified:

```
[Serializable]
[ActiveRecord("my_table", Schema = "my_schema", UseAutoImport = false, Mutable = false)]
public class MyTable : MyServerActiveRecord<MyTable> //Extension of ActiveRecordBase<>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Identity, "my_pk")]
    public int ID {get;set;}

    [Property("my_column1")]
    public int MyColumn1 {get;set;}

    [Property("my_column2")]
    public int MyColumn2 {get;set;}
}
```

And the method with my HQL

```
public static int GetSum(int num1){
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery(@"
        select sum(case when t.MyColumn2 = 2 then 1 else 0 end)             
        from My.Complete.Namespace.MyTable t 
        where t.MyColumn1 = :num  
        group by t.MyColumn1 
    ");
    query.SetParameter("num", num1);
    return query.UniqueResult<Int32>();
}
```

Using `SetInt32` instead of `SetParameter` didn't work. I verified the spacing in the query.

The query works fine if I throw a `7` where `:num` is and cut out `:num` and its set statement entirely.

Comment: I never seen such a trouble. May you inspect `query.NamedParameters` to see what it finds in your `HQL` query?

Comment: @Frédéric, no luck, NamedParameters has a length of zero after defining the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was populating my session variable like this:

```
session = ActiveRecordMediator.GetSessionFactoryHolder().GetSessionFactory(typeof(T)).OpenSession();
```

where T = the query return type, aka `Int32`.

I changed T to be the class I was querying on, `MyTable`, and everything started working. Bummer that Castle/NHibernate doesn't return a more helpful error.
My bad for not including the session line in the question.